# How to limit max version of a transitive dependency

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, dependencies, build.gradle

I have a problem about how to specify the max version for a transitive dependency. Let me explain this with an example:

My app uses the library `library-foo`, the problem is that library-foo version 3.0+ introduces breaking changes and my app is not ready yet. So I declare it in my dependencies:

```
implementation 'com.example:library-foo:(,3.0)'
```

My problem comes when I introduce a new dependency, lets say `library-bar`. That library introduces a transitive dependency on `library-foo`

```
library-bar 5.0   -depends on-> library-foo 2.2
library-bar 5.5   -depends on-> library-foo 3.1
```

So, after adding the new dependency:

```
implementation 'com.example:library-foo:(,3.0)'
implementation 'com.example:library-bar:5.+'
```

I was hopping the dependency resolution to be smart enough. Gradle included the 5.5 version, introducing the breaking changes in my project.

I know I could also limit the max version of `library-bar` but in projects with a lot of dependencies, it would be great to declare my max version of the troublesome library (foo in this case) forcing the rest of dependencies to be adapted to this.

Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use gradle's [`constraints`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_constraints.html#sec:adding-constraints-transitive-deps):

```
implementation 'com.example:library-foo:3.0'
implementation 'com.example:library-bar:5.+'
constraints {
  implementation('com.example:library-foo:3.0') {
    because 'Versions greater than 3.0 introduce bugs'
  }
}
```